# adding percentage of sales

Tags: sql-server

I have have a query that returns sales total per vendor and location. How would I add a column for percentage of total sales for the date selected. Using sql 2005

```
  SELECT vendor,
         location,
         sum(ExtPrice) as total   
    FROM [database].[dbo].[GetOrderDetails]
   where processdate > '2010-05-08 16:35:46.500'
group by vendor,location
order by vendor asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want your code to look like the below, using a computed column

```
PercentageOfTotal AS (ExtPrice / sum(ExtPrice))
```

you could possibly use total in place of the sum(ExtPrice), but I'm not certain you can target another computed column. worth a shot though

Comment: I was missing a closing Parenthesis. Unless you tried that already

Comment: Alternatively, I may have them in the wrong order, you might be able to just run it as ExtPrice/sum(ExtPrice) AS PercentageOfTotal

Comment: Well that raises a whole new interesting issue. That means that sum(ExtPrice) is coming back as zero. Just to confirm, when you run the query as listed above, you get something other than zero in the total column, right?

Comment: There are some vendors with sales of 0

Comment: and is SUM(ExtPrice) a total for an individual vendor's sales, or total sales for the whole d-base. Because if the former, then it only makes sense that you'd get a division by zero. But that doesn't seem right to me. However, if that's the case, you'd need to wrap in a CASE statement to confirm that you aren't dividing by zero before executing the percentage statement.

Comment: case when sum(ExtPrice) = 0 then null else (ExtPrice / sum(ExtPrice)) end as PercentageOfTotal